# check for file string if true create new file based on file string

Tags: bash, filenames

Situation:

AVI files sometimes come in two files filename-cd1.avi and filename-cd2.avi.

I use the following line in a bash script on my iMac to copy the two cd files into a single AVI file:

MENCODER -ovc copy -oac copy *CD1.avi *CD2.avi -o "Joined Movie.avi" > /dev/null 2>&1

What I'd like to do is retain the base file name. So:

of file name with '-cd2' is found, like say: OldMovie-cd2.avi

What I'm wanting to do is store "OldMovie" as a variable so that I can tell mencoder to perform the copy on the two files and… Here's the kicker - I'd LOVE to have resulting file be "OldMovie.avi" which is the base name of the two cd sub files.

Make sense? Geez I hope so.

Appreciate the help, I've googled for hours without a solution.

Randy

Answer (score 1):

```
for avi in *-cd2.avi; do

    base=`echo $avi | sed 's+-cd2\.avi+$\.avi+g'`
    echo base is $base
    echo looking for ${base}-cd1.avi
    if [ -f "${base}-cd1.avi" ]; then
         echo Found ${base}-cd1.avi
         MENCODER -ovc copy -oac copy ${base}-cd1.avi ${base}-cd2.avi -o "${base}.avi" > /dev/null 2>&1
    else
         echo Did not find ${base}-cd1.avi
    fi
done
```

Comment: OMG - wow, thanks for the fast reply. I'll test this out, anxiouslyl

Comment: ls -1 *-cd2.avi finds the file but the IF statement never executes. Not sure if something is wrong in the "base" line or the IF statement.

Comment: I have added some echo statements for debugging.  These should help explain why the condition is not met.

Comment: It may have been that I misunderstood the problem.  The logic I provided runs the MENCODER command if it find BOTH filename-cd2.avi AND filename-cd1.avi.

Comment: Also `base=${avi%-cd2.avi}` more idiomatic, less error-prone, and saves two external processes.

Comment: Success! Using the base routine from EJK, and a little change from triple made it a success. I'm stoked.